# Cordova / Phonegap ignores height value of div in iOS

Tags: ios, css, cordova

I'm new to Cordova. I set a div to height: 100%; width: 100%

The width is respected perfectly but height is completely ignored in iOS. Even if I try changing it to 50%, 200% etc. Div height works just fine in Android, it takes up 100% of the screen.

Any idea how I can get around this? Thanks!

Comment: try `height: 100vh;` and `width:100vw;`

Comment: Works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `line-height:100%;` along with `height:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your css with viewport sizes : `height: 100vh; and width:100vw;`
`vh` is the vertical height of your screen and `vw` is the width.
More info can be found [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)